# System() to start a process, but using CreateProcess fails?

Tags: c++, windows, process

So, curious problem, I'm trying to create a process, and then resume it, mostly exploring the Windows API. I've noticed that if I do this:

```
system("C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe");
```

It will open a calculator exe, however if I try to do the same thing using `CreateProcessA`, I get this:

```
STARTUPINFO starting_info;
PROCESS_INFORMATION process_info;

// let's try and make a process
if (!CreateProcessA(NULL, "C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe", NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &starting_info, &process_info)) {
    return;
}
// resume thread
NtResumeThread(process_info.hThread, NULL);
```

This for some reason throws an error of `0xc0000142` most of the times when it "creates" the process, else it just fails.

What's going on?

Comment: `STARTUPINFOA starting_info = {sizeof(starting_info)};`

Comment: @ChristopherOicles Why is that needed?

Comment: @Link Please consider reading the documentation

Comment: Initialization of the size of the structure is needed, because the pointer can address either a STARTUPINFO or STARTUPINFOEX object. The system knows what object has been passed from the size of `cb` value that indicates the size.

Comment: Marius is correct, also that initialization zeroes-out the fields following cb.  In addition, you are explicitly calling the ANSI version of CreateProcess, so you also want to explicitly use the ANSI version of STARTUP_INFO, just in case this ends up in a Unicode build.  PROCESS_INFORMATION does not have different ANSI and Wide versions because it doesn't involve strings.  One other thing, the command line string should be writable, not constant like your literal -- however I'm not sure what the circumstances are under which passing a constant string would actually cause problems.

Comment: @ChristopherOicles, normally it is a string, but I just cut out the part that made the string and just put the value in there for sake of brevity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following MSDN sample code for creating a process: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512(v=vs.85).aspx

You need to zero out the `si` and `pi` structs, also set

```
si.cb = sizeof(si);
```

In the end, close process and thread handles.

```
CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
```

Comment: You don't need to initialise the process information struct

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You are correct. The process info struct is an out argument. Initializing it (`PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = { 0 };`) is not a must.